# NPM Global Package CLI not found in OSX terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, express, npm, command-line-interface

I'm having an issue when installing express and express-generator and trying to use the express cli to generate stuff.

Everything goes great when I use `npm install -g express` and `npm install -g express-generator`, but after restarting terminal, but I can't use `express` [as per the express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

After a bit of investigation, I've found that `express` and `express-generator` are bing installed to:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules`

However, the only packages that work on my machine (like Yeoman, Grunt, stuff I regularly use without issue) is installed here:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

So what's the deal here? Why are my `install -g` packages going into a `node/lib/node_modules`?

I've tried using `export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules:$PATH` in my `.bash_profile`, as well, but that doesn't seem to help me out here.

Comment: What does `npm bin -g` return?

Comment: I wound up just ripping my node installation out and then reinstalling via nvm. Now it works properly.

Comment: @robertklep I have the same problem but, even if I have it installed several times it does not change anything.
The `npm bin -g` return `/Users/username/.npm-global/bin
(not in PATH env variable)`